# git: Cannot see HEAD pointer of the remote (upstream) repo

Tags: git, git-remote

I have configured 2 remote repos in `git`

```
(develop)$ git remote -v
origin  git@gitlab:pkaramol/aproject.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitlab:pkaramol/aproject.git (push)
upstream    git@gitlab:anothernamespace/aproject.git (fetch)
upstream    no-push (push)
```

This is according to the known fork and pull from the `upstream` workflow; so that I can work on my forked project and periodically pull updates from the `upstream` and push them to my fork (`origin`).

However, I was wondering what is the current branch the `upstream`'s `HEAD` is pointing to, in order for me to know when running (being on my `master` branch): `git pull upstream master`

which `upstream` branch will be fetched and merged in my local `master`.

But after running:

```
$ git branch -av
* master                                                 aa8a454 A commit message
  remotes/origin/HEAD                                     -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master                                  aa8a454 A commit message
  remotes/upstream/master                                aa8a454 A commit message
  remotes/upstream/feature_branch_1                      3fo2090 Another commit message
```

Why isn't there a `remotes/upstream/HEAD` reference?

How can I know what branch the `upstream`'s `HEAD` is pointing to?

Comment: I guess you are using some Git tool instead of Git commands and `remotes/origin/HEAD` was created by this tool. When you run `git pull upstream master`, the `master` in `upstream`, aka `git@gitlab:anothernamespace/aproject.git`, will be fetched and merged. If `git@gitlab:anothernamespace/aproject.git` is a bare repository, then it has no `HEAD` because it has no working tree. You can run `git ls-remote upstream master` to see what commit it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`git ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote):

```
git ls-remote upstream
```

That will list its HEAD.
That is mentioned at the bottom of the page "[GitHub: Setting the default branch](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-the-default-branch/)".